# Retrieve Username of current logged user via WMI (C#)

Tags: c#, wmi

When I try to retrieve the currently logged user via WMI, on a remote machine, it always returns an empty string, as all other request works well.

```
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\10.156.127.54\\root\\cimv2", options);
            scope.Connect();

            ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Environment");
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

            foreach (ManagementObject foundObjects in searcher.Get())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name         : {0}", foundObjects["Name"]);
                Console.WriteLine("Domain       : {0}", foundObjects["Domain"]);
                Console.WriteLine("UserName     : {0}", foundObjects["UserName"]);
                //lbl_logged_user.Content = foundObjects["Version"];
            }
```

I really don't understand why...
I also tried with Win32_LoggedOnUser, but without any result too.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Could you try changing your query to "SELECT username FROM Win32_ComputerSystem"

Comment: Thank's for your reply. It returns me a list of users who have already logged in. I need only one result, i.e. the currently connected user.

Comment: Are you open to non-WMI methods?

Comment: It depends :) what were you thinking ?